# How to handle dynamic footnote with a text box

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting, footnote

I'm creating some financial models that require a lot of footnotes. I should preface by saying they're not actually footnotes, it's a text box below the main table since it takes up half the sheet. My current sheet has 10-12 footnotes with a decent amount of explanation for each footnote. My process is to basically type out the row titles and have a number (1) in smaller font at the end.

Then i'll have a text box that contains (1) and the corresponding explanation.

The problem is that it's a very iterative process and while I'm going through it if I end up changing the location of one row or inserting a new item, I'll have to go through and manually change all the numbers in the title as well as the corresponding text box footnotes. It's extremely tedious and was wondering if there was a way to add more dynamism to the process.

Comment: Have you though of using comments instead? ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-comments-and-notes-in-excel-bdcc9f5d-38e2-45b4-9a92-0b2b5c7bf6f8)). The comment will appear when hovering over the cell.

Comment: yea unfortunately I need them printed for presentations. It'll have to be in the format of a financial statement

Comment: Comments are printed at the bottom of the sheet.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the problem, but I often use text boxes and have the contents display whatever's typed in another cell. For example, my footnote is found in cell F1. Then with my cursor in my textbox, I go up to the formula bar and type "=F1".

Comment: @Isolated sorry if that wasn't clear. Basically, if i have 10 items from my table that need to be footnoted and they all have corresponding text boxes that start with its identifying number (for example (2)) and then will have a blurb about Accounts Payable (assuming that's the line item in the table with (2). If I end up moving Accounts Payable to the bottom of my table now, It would be weird to have the #2 all the way at the bottom, so I go through and manually change all the numbers on the table, then go to my text box and manually change the numbers there as well. Does that make any sense?